# Pipeline with grep and find prints numbers infront of result

Tags: shell, find, grep

Am using the following "find" command to extract some files,

```
find /lag/cnnf/ -maxdepth 3 -newer ./start ! -newer ./end | grep -nri abc | egrep '([^0-9]45[^0-9])' | grep -nri "db.tar.gz" >> sample.txt
```

My output in sample.txt is

```
5:175:/lag/cnnf/abc/45/r-01.bac.db.tar.gz
20:190:/lag/cnnf/abc/45/r-01.bac.db.tar.gz
```

what should i do to get only,

```
/lag/cnnf/abc/45/r-01.bac.db.tar.gz
/lag/cnnf/abc/45/r-01.bac.db.tar.gz
```

without the random numbers in front of it and what those numbers actually mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers come from the `-n` options you are passing to `grep`. However, the pipe as you have it is a bit too long for my taste.

From your example it seems you have a reasonably simple directory structure. If you have the GNU find, use `-regex` (I'm not sure this is mandated by POSIX):

```sh
find /lag/cnnf/ \
    -maxdepth 3 \
    -regex "abc.*[^0-9]45[^0-9].*db.tar.gz" \
    -newer ./start ! -newer ./end >> sample.txt
```

Otherwise, assuming a little bit stricter requirements on the directory structure (would still fit your example):

```sh
find /lag/cnnf/ \
    -maxdepth 3 \
    -path "*abc*/45/*db.tar.gz" \
    -newer ./start ! -newer ./end >> sample.txt
```

You might also want to consider using shell expansion - for example in `bash` you would need to set the shell option `globstar` and then play with matching using the `**` wildcard.

Comment: Neither `-regex` nor `-maxdepth` are POSIX. They're both GNU, but are now also supported by some BSDs. `-maxdepth` can be replaced by a combination of `-path` (recent POSIX addition) and `-prune`.

Answer (score 6):

The numbers are actually produced by `(e)grep`s and its `-n` option which means:

> Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.

If you insist on keeping that option, remove first two fields separated by a colon with the `cut` command:

```sh
find /lag/cnnf/ -maxdepth 3 -newer ./start ! -newer ./end \
    | grep -nri abc \
    | egrep '([^0-9]45[^0-9])' \
    | grep -nri "db.tar.gz" \
    | cut -d':' -f3- >> sample.txt
```

`-d` is character used as field separator, `-f` says which fields to print, in this case the 3rd one and all following.